# How to go back multiple pages in one back press with page_transition in flutter

Tags: flutter, mobile, mobile-application, flutter-animation

I am new to flutter development and facing the below issue:
I have a stack of screens in my flutter application as follows,

Take Test -> Rules -> Question Set -> Review Answers -> Success

I need to navigate from Success to Rules on back icon click.

1. Initially I used Navigator.push but going back in the intended way was difficult.
2. I am hence using Navigator.pushReplacement but in this case, page_transition is not working.
3. Using Navigator.pushAndRemoveUntil, the rules screen is visible but on further back press a blank screen is displayed instead of Take Test screen.

I need a solution which would allow me to go back multiple screens along with the page_transition working properly.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

the correct solution is Navigator.pushAndRemoveUntil. I need to see the code for tell you why when you go back the screen is blank instead of Take test screen. Be sure you don't lose the reference of that page.